# Como dar Split em Javascript usando múltiplos separadores e sem removê-los?

Tags: javascript, string, regex, split

Tenho o seguinte código em JavaScript:

```
 if (v.includes("'!'"))
                var separators = ["\\\''", '\\\&', '\\\#', '\\\|'];
            else
                var separators = ["\\\''", '\\\'', '\\\&', '\\\#', '\\\|'];
            var variables = v.split(new RegExp(separators.join('|'), 'g'));
```

Onde `variables` seria um array com meu split, preciso de um split usando múltiplos separadores e sem que eles sejam removidos do array resultante.

Ex:

```
"Teste1 & Teste2 # Teste3"  -> 
1:Teste1 
2:& 
3:Teste3 
4:# 
5:Teste3
```

Comment: seu regex precisa ser melhorado para aceitar termos, você está jogando tudo dentro dele sem setar inicio ou fim ou condição, exemplo ^/(termo1)(termo2)(termo3/$g, tipo isso e tal

Comment: Não entendi muito bem o que você quer fazer... Tente [edit] a sua pergunta, de modo a acrescentar mais detalhes.

Comment: `'Teste1 & Teste2 # Teste3'.split(' ')` não atende o que precisa?

Answer (score 1):

Use grupo de captura para que os caracteres da regex no split sejam incluídos na array resultante. Basta incluir a regex concatenando entre parênteses `()`.

Por exemplo, a regex `/,/` no `"a,b".split(/,/)` irá resultar na array `["a", "b"]`.

```js
console.log("a,b".split(/,/));
```

Já usando grupo de captura `(,)`, a vírgula também é incluída na array, resultando em `["a", ",", "b"]`:

```js
console.log("a,b".split(/(,)/));
```

Então, basta concatenar os parênteses no padrão do `RegExp`:

```
v.split(new RegExp('('+separators.join('|')+')', 'g'))
                    ↑                        ↑
```

Veja:

```js
var v = "Teste1 & Teste2 # Teste3";
var separators = ["\\\''", '\\\'', '\\\&', '\\\#', '\\\|'];
var variables = v.split(new RegExp('('+separators.join('|')+')', 'g')).map(function(i){
   return i.trim();
});
console.log(variables);
```

> Veja que usei um `.map()` adicional com `.trim()` para remover os
>   espaços.

Answer (score 1):

Uma coisa não ficou muito clara (como já indicado nos comentários): no seu exemplo, os espaços são removidos do resultado final. Tanto que, para obter exatamente o que foi indicado, bastaria fazer um `split` pelos espaços:

```js
console.log("Teste1 & Teste2 # Teste3".split(' '));
```

---

Assumindo que essa questão do espaço foi um pequeno engano, e você quer de fato fazer um `split` e incluir os separadores no resultado final, então basta usar um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), conforme indicado na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/425806/112052). Isso funciona porque [segundo a documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split#Description), quando a regex possui grupos de captura, estes também são incluídos no resultado do `split`.

Agora, uma pequena sugestão de melhoria: se todos os separadores são formados por **apenas um caractere**, não precisa fazer `join('|')`. Basta colocar todas as opções em uma [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

Por exemplo, se os separadores podem ser `&`, `|` ou `#`, basta usar a regex `[&|#]` (e dentro de colchetes, muitos caracteres "perdem seus poderes especiais" e não precisam ser escapados com `\` - o caractere `|`, por exemplo, não precisa ser escapado neste caso). A regex `[&|#]` significa "o caractere `&`, **ou** `|`, **ou** `#`" (qualquer um deles serve).

Exemplo:

```js
let texto = "Teste1 & Teste2 # Teste3";
let separators = ["'", '\'', '&', '#', '|'];
let partes = texto.split(new RegExp('(['+ separators.join('') + '])'));
console.log(partes);
```

Repare que eu junto todos os separadores, coloco entre `[]` para formar a classe de caracteres, e coloco tudo isso entre parênteses para formar o grupo de captura. Outro detalhe é que não precisa passar a *flag* `g` para o construtor de `RegExp` - esta *flag* influencia na busca e substituição (em métodos como `match`, `exec` e `replace`), mas no `split` não faz diferença.

Um detalhe é que a solução acima inclui os espaços no resultado final. Não ficou claro se  os espaços devem ou não ser removidos (a descrição da pergunta dá a entender que não, mas o exemplo dado sugere que sim). Caso tenha que remover os espaços, basta usar `map` juntamente com `trim`, como a outra resposta já indicou.

Lembrando novamente que o uso de `[]` só funciona quando os separadores contém apenas um caractere. Se eles puderem ter mais de um caractere, aí o jeito é usar `|` como você já estava fazendo (com o detalhe que nem todos os caracteres precisam ser escapados com `\`, como o `&` e o `#`, por exemplo).

Outro detalhe (que provavelmente não passa de micro-otimização) é que a classe de caracteres é mais rápida: compare [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/cTtPQA/1) e [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/cTtPQA/2/) a quantidade de passos de cada opção. Obviamente que para poucas strings pequenas, a diferença será insignificante, mas de qualquer forma, fica aí registrada a diferença entre as duas opções.